# Use Confirmation Dialog and Get Its Result at Run Time in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 'delete' button in my asp.net application. I want to put a confirmation dialog with YES and NO buttons and when i click on the YES button `(if result="YES")`, the function will continue; and if i click on the NO button `(if result="NO")`, the function will exit.

I made it first with `DialogResult` and `MessageBox` but `MessageBox` doesnt run at asp.net.

I have added the previous code of my function. Can you help me about that issue. What can i use instead of `MessageBox` for confirmation.

Thanks in advance.

**MY CODE**

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isRefresh)
    {
        List<Object> secilenler = grdMalzeme.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID");
        if (secilenler.Count > 0)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(new Form() 
                { TopMost = true }, 
                "ARE YOU SURE?", 
                "Confirmation",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
                (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000
                );
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                List<Item> secilen3;
                for (int i = 0; i < secilenler.Count; i++)
                {
                    secilen3 = Items.Where(a => a.ID == Convert.ToInt32(secilenler[i])).ToList();
                    Items.Remove(secilen3[0]);
                }

                grdMalzeme.DataSource = Items;
                grdMalzeme.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, 
                   "Seçim Yapmadınız!");

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
                "Pop", "openModal();", true);
        }
    }
    uploadedImage.ImageUrl = "";
    grdMalzeme.DataSource = Items;
    grdMalzeme.DataBind();
    grdMalzeme.Selection.UnselectAll();
    grdMalzeme.FocusedRowIndex = -1;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(),
        "disableKalip", "disableKalip();", true);
}
```

Comment: You're missing some fundamental understanding of how web applications are different from desktop applications.  If you want a "pop up" confirmation then you would display that *on the client* with JavaScript.  If you want a series of pages as a response then you can have an entire page be the "confirmation".  Send the user to that page, and the button they click on that page indicates their response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add attribute onclick on page_load in your specific .cs file

```
youButtonId.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Confirm To Do 
Action?');");
```

Hope this will solve your Problem